# Send email in real time with SFMC connected with Salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

The sync of data between SFMC and Salesforce CRM when the MC connector is in place, has at least 15 minutes delay, which is too long for some client use cases.

We need to send transactionnal messages, in near real time with data from Salesforce CRM.

Do the Triggered Sends in Salesforce with the MC Connector allow real time send email (or near real time) ?
(cf link : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_triggered_sends.htm&type=5)

And what about triggering an email with Journey Builder using the Salesforce Data Event ? Is it also real time (or near real time) ?

Or should we rather develop API calls to get real time trigger ? What would you recommend for real time ?

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, both Triggered Sends from CRM as well as Salesforce Data Entry Events happen near real time, based on changes in records within CRM objects. This follows a very different route than the data sync to Synchronised Data Extensions. Basically this is driven by Process Builder in CRM, which monitors records continuously and uses SFMC API to call the appropriate endpoint of either Triggered Send or Journey Entry, passing the appropriate data to it.

Keep in mind, that both Triggered Sends and Journey Builder Sends (being technically "disguised" Triggered Sends) are not entirely real time. Their performance depends on the priority of the send, which you select:

- **High** – Queued immediately. Using this setting requires an additional cost.
- **Medium** – Queued every minute by default. It can take up to 1 minute to send the email.
- **Low** – Queued every 5 minutes. It can take up to 5 minutes to send the email.

Meaning that in case you use the default, medium setting, you will often experience at least one minute wait between a contact reaches Send Email activity and email being sent.

Do observe, that data you select in Salesforce Data Entry event is static, as it reflects the state of CRM records at journey injection time. If you have a decision split shortly after injection, and wish to utilise Contact Data, you might experience issues of sync not having passed the data from CRM to SFMC yet. I outline some options for speeding up this process in my answer in this thread:
[Marketing Cloud Journey with short wait times and use of synchronized data extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294980/marketing-cloud-journey-with-short-wait-times-and-use-of-synchronized-data-exten/295023#295023)

Comment: Thank you very for your replies (and all your replies on my numerous questions...!) Is it possible to use Marketing Cloud Connect Triggered Sends and APEX to trigger - in real time - SMS and mobile Push with Salesforce CRM data ? Or it is only for email sends ? Thank you

Comment: @LudivineL - you can't do this out of the box, but you should be able to do this by implementing the API call to SFMC with APEX trigger in Core.

Comment: OK, so if we prefer using an out of the box "near real time" solution, it would be better to trigger SMS and Push notification with Journey Builder and the Salesforce Data Entry event ? Thank you

Comment: Correct, @LudivineL

Comment: if we want to have specific delay 5 minutes for example, can we use Salesforce Data Event (Medium priority) in Entry source, then a Wait activity of 4 minutes, and then the Mobile Push actiivty ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, @LudivineL